# Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement

Tags: powershell

```
$TargetEmails | Where-Object { 
$_.contains ( $TargetHeader ) }

Error: Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
```

I've tried using "$TargetHeader", '$TargetHeader', { ( $*.contains ( ) ) }, { ( $*.contains " " ) }, { ( $_.contains ' ' ) } and continue to receive the same error respective to the changed context.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See
[PowerTip: Line Continuation in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-line-continuation-in-powershell/) :

> Question:  What the line continuation character should use to ensure
> my Windows PowerShell code continues to the next line?
>
> Answer: The line continuation character in Windows PowerShell is the
> backtick. Type a `<space>`, the backtick, and then press ENTER, for
> example:
>
> ```
> Get-Process -Name `
> "Powershell_ISE"
> ```

You were using line-continuation incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$TargetEmails  | Where-Object {$_.contains($TargetHeader)}
```

All I did was remove some white space.